# How do I customise the resource key lookup for spring MVC validation messages

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bean-validation

The default behaviour for the resource key look seems to be to prefix the field name with the constraint. I would like to post fix it instead.

```
public class MyForm {
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
}
```

In my `messages.properties`:

```
myForm.name=The label
NotEmpty.myForm.name=Please enter your name
```

I would like to use:

```
myForm.name=The label
myForm.name.NotEmpty=Please enter your name
```

This obviously purely cosmetic, but my OCD can't handle the look of my resource file.

I'm using spring 3.1.2 with hibernate validator 4.3.0.Final. The application it's self is using the `@Configuration`, `@EnableWebMvc` and `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` style configuration, but I should be able to translate any xml based solution.

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea is to extend [`DefaultMessageCodesResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html) and override the method `postProcessMessageCode()` which originally is:

```
protected String postProcessMessageCode(String code) {
    return getPrefix() + code;
}
```

and change it the way you desire. I believe Spring will pickup your bean of type `MessageCodesResolver` as the default behavior when bootstrapping. Hope this helps.

In [Spring 3.1+](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6506?focusedCommentId=62729&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-62729), now you can configure a message codes resolver through `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. It seems that support for the Java API will come in [3.2](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#getMessageCodesResolver%28%29).

Comment: You've given me just enough there... the actual solution requires reimplementing DefaultMessageCodesResolver, I've created a gist https://gist.github.com/3150779 with my working solution.